# How to pass validation error to child control in reusable UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding, wpf-controls

I've created my own `UserControl`, called `PersonNameControl` which is intented to be reused.
The control has three `TextBox` fields, and has three dependency properties in its class file.

- Firstname
- Insertion
- Lastname

Each dependency property value is bound to to a field, so the dependency property *Firstname* is bound to the *Firstname* `TextBox`, and so on.

I conciously didn't explicitly set the DataContext of the UserControl.
The control should be as loosely as possible. It should only get it's values (for the fields) via its dependency properties. It shouldn't even be looking to anything like DataContext.

```xml
    <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.PersonNameControl">
        <StackPanel>

            <Label>Firstname:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Firstname, Mode=TwoWay,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
            </TextBox>

            <Label>Insertion:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Insertion, Mode=TwoWay,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
            </TextBox>

            <Label>Lastname:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Lastname, Mode=TwoWay,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
            </TextBox>

        </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
```

And the control class:

```cs
public partial class PersonNameControl : UserControl
{
    public PersonNameControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Firstname
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FirstnameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FirstnameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstnameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Firstname", typeof(string), typeof(PersonNameControl), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));


    public string Insertion
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(InsertionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InsertionProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InsertionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Insertion", typeof(string), typeof(PersonNameControl), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));


    public string Lastname
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LastnameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LastnameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LastnameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Lastname", typeof(string), typeof(PersonNameControl), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
}
```

The control is supposed to be used inside another view as follows:

```xml
<!-- 
Here we are inside a view or some other control.
The bindings here provide the dependency properties of the UserControl with a value.
The DataContext of the view where my UserControl is used, is a ViewModel that implements INotifyDataErrorInfo 
-->

<myControls:PersonNameControl 
    Firstname="{Binding SomeFirstnameFromVM, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Insertion="{Binding SomeInsertionFromVM, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Lastname="{Binding SomeLastnameFromVM, Mode=TwoWay}">
</myControls:PersonNameControl>
```

When the ViewModel (implements INotifyDataErrorInfo) created a Validation error, nothing happens with my `PersonNameControl` UserControl.
I managed in making a control that is independent because it doesn't rely on a specific DataContext, doesn't set its own DataContext in its codebehind file, and just gets its values via dependency properties. The values are exchanged via the bindings and show up, but the validation errors don't show.
What I want is passing the validation errors through, to the UserControl.

Some solutions on the internet make use of `ValidationAdornerSite` and I tried this. But this would only work for one `TextBox`.

I don't see any solution without making my control dependent on the outside world or introducing ugly extra properties to solve it cumbersome. I thought the errors are 'tunneled' like a piece of information through all bindings towards the last level where the value arrives. But this seems not to be the right consideration.

**Edit:**

I added my ViewModel class.

```cs
public class CustomerFormViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    protected string _clientNumber;
    protected DateTime _date;
    protected string _firstname;
    protected string _insertion;
    protected string _lastname;
    protected Address _address;
    protected ObservableCollection<Email> _emails;
    protected ObservableCollection<PhoneNumber> _phoneNumbers;
    protected string _note;

    protected bool _hasErrors;
    protected IList<ValidationFailure> _validationErrors;

    public IList<ValidationFailure> ValidationErrors
    {
        get { return _validationErrors; }
        set { _validationErrors = value; OnPropertyChanged("ValidationErrors"); }
    }

    public string ClientNumber
    {
        get { return _clientNumber; }
        set { _clientNumber = value; OnPropertyChanged("ClientNumber"); }
    }
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set { _date = value; OnPropertyChanged("Date"); }
    }
    public string Firstname
    {
        get { return _firstname; }
        set { _firstname = value; OnPropertyChanged("Firstname"); }
    }
    public string Insertion
    {
        get { return _insertion; }
        set { _insertion = value; OnPropertyChanged("Insertion"); }
    }
    public string Lastname
    {
        get { return _lastname; }
        set { _lastname = value; OnPropertyChanged("Lastname"); }
    }
    public Address Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set { _address = value; OnPropertyChanged("Address"); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Email> Emails
    {
        get { return _emails; }
        set { _emails = value; OnPropertyChanged("Emails"); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers
    {
        get { return _phoneNumbers; }
        set { _phoneNumbers = value; OnPropertyChanged("PhoneNumbers"); }
    }
    public string Note
    {
        get { return _note; }
        set { _note = value; OnPropertyChanged("Note"); }
    }

    private DelegateCommand _saveCustomerCommand;

    public DelegateCommand SaveCustomerCommand
    {
        get { return _saveCustomerCommand; }
        private set { _saveCustomerCommand = value; OnPropertyChanged("SaveCustomerCommand"); }
    }

    public CustomerFormViewModel()
    {
        ValidationErrors = new List<ValidationFailure>();
        SaveCustomerCommand = new DelegateCommand(SaveCustomer, CanSaveCustomer);
    }

    protected void ValidateInput()
    {
        ValidationErrors.Clear();

        CustomerFormValidator validator = new CustomerFormValidator();
        FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(this);

        ValidationErrors = result.Errors;

        foreach (ValidationFailure f in ValidationErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.ErrorMessage);
        }

        _hasErrors = result.Errors.Count != 0;

        List<string> vmProperties = new List<string>() { "Firstname", "Lastname", "Address", "ClientNumber", "Date" };

        foreach (string propertyName in vmProperties)
        {
            OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get { return _hasErrors; }
    }

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    protected void OnErrorsChanged(string name)
    {
        ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        return ValidationErrors.Where<ValidationFailure>(x => x.PropertyName == propertyName);
    }

    public void SaveCustomer(object parameter)
    {
        this.ValidateInput();

        if( ! HasErrors)
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer(-1, ClientNumber, Date, Firstname, Insertion, Lastname, Address);

            ICustomerRepository repo = new CustomerRepository();
            bool res = repo.SaveCustomer(customer);

            if(res) {
                // ...
            }
            // ...

        } else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("One or more fields are not filled in correctly.", "Invalid input", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }

    public bool CanSaveCustomer(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have been also dealing with that problem. There is no too much options, you might be considering using INotifyDataErrorInfo with UserControl. And you can register your viewmodel as INotifyDataErrorInfo to get the logic from VM.

Comment: @Ugur Did you solve it the way you tell? If so, can you tell me more about it? Or even place an answer if this is the best option.

Comment: Can you post your view model with `INotifyDataErrorInfo` implementation.

Comment: I added my ViewModel class in the question.

Comment: Where `ValidateInput` being called?

Comment: Oh there's a part missing in the class. There also was a Command attached to a button in the view for submitting the form. The Command executed a method SaveCustomer, and in that method my `ValidateInput` is used. I will update the code in my question later.

Comment: @user2190492 I have added a demo, you can check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have prepared a demo user control. It is a sub user control, gets all validation info from its MainViewModel

[image]

MainWindow

```
<Window
    x:Class="ValidationSubUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ValidationSubUI"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Name="MyWindow"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <local:SubUserControl
            FirstName="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"
            LastName="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ValidationSource="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=DataContext}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainViewModel

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ValidationSubUI
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        public string Error
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        private string m_FirstName;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return m_FirstName; }
            set
            {
                m_FirstName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string m_LastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return m_LastName; }
            set
            {
                m_LastName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                if (columnName == nameof(FirstName))
                {
                    return GetFirstNameError();
                }
                else if (columnName == nameof(LastName))
                {
                    return GetLastNameError();
                }

                return null;
            }
        }

        private string GetFirstNameError()
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
            {
                result = "First name required";
            }

            return result;
        }

        private string GetLastNameError()
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
            {
                result = "Last name required";
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

SubUserControl gets all validation logic from MainViewModel

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace ValidationSubUI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for SubUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SubUserControl : UserControl, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        public SubUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public IDataErrorInfo ValidationSource
        {
            get { return (IDataErrorInfo)GetValue(ValidationSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValidationSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ValidationSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidationSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ValidationSource", typeof(IDataErrorInfo), typeof(SubUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));



        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(FirstNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FirstName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FirstName", typeof(string), typeof(SubUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));



        public string LastName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LastNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LastNameProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LastName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LastNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LastName", typeof(string), typeof(SubUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


        public string Error
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                if (ValidationSource != null)
                {
                    return ValidationSource[columnName];
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and SubUserControl

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="ValidationSubUI.SubUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Name="CustomControl"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="controlWithError" />
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock
                                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                FontSize="12"
                                FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                Foreground="Red"
                                Text="{Binding ElementName=controlWithError, Path=AdornedElement.ToolTip, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{x:Reference Name=CustomControl}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox
                Width="120"
                Height="30"
                Margin="5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />

            <TextBox
                Width="120"
                Height="30"
                Margin="5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: It is a solution, but the property name on the view model of the parent control, has to be the same as the name of the dependency property in the SubUserControl.

Comment: Yes it should be. but if not, it does not create also problem